# open purchase order overview form from custom form

Tags: forms, oracle, oracleforms, oracle-ebs

How can I open the po-overview form with a po_header_id from a custom form?

This works pretty fine for the standart po form but not for the overview:

```
fnd_function.execute (function_name => 'PO_POXPOEPO', 
                                            open_flag     => 'Y', 
                                            session_flag  => 'N', 
                                            other_params  => ' PO_HEADER_ID="'||PO_HEADER_ID||'"  ACCESS_LEVEL_CODE="VIEW_ONLY" POXPOEPO_CALLING_FORM="POXSTNOT"' );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
DECLARE
  pl_id        PARAMLIST;
BEGIN
  pl_id := Get_Parameter_List('yourprm');
  IF NOT Id_Null(pl_id) THEN  
    destroy_parameter_list(pl_id);
  end if;
  pl_id := create_parameter_list('yourprm');
  add_parameter(pl_id, 'po_header_id', text_parameter, 'yourpoid');

  CALL_FORM('po-overview',
              no_hide,
              no_replace,
              no_query_only,
              pl_id);
END;
```